# To transfer data from one wksht to another where cell value = wksht name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I would like to use a macro to transfer data from worksheets in a workbook to a master page using a macro.  On the Master page is a list of worksheet names and would like to pull the data from the worksheet to the corresponding row on the Master sheet(where A2 = wksht name).  The data is not in 0ne row, it would be from multiple cells but across the row on the Master sheet.  Any help with how to direct the Macro to do this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance :)
For example:

Master

[image]

Wksht1

[image]

Comment: I have not got the idea of data structure in Wksht1...
Do you actually need headers from the Master sheet to be dropped down to Wksht1 as values? ( like "Price" and "Number" in your pic.)

Comment: FYI this belongs on SuperUser, not Stack Overflow. Also, it's important to show your work (what have you tried? where are you stuck?). Then, please see this - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Finally: please edit your title and fully spell out everything - abbreviating worksheet as "wksht" isn't going to help, when people search.

Comment: ok re worded and reposted in stack superusers.  I do not have any code started because I do not have a clue how to start this one. The goal of the macro would be to copy a multiple cells of data "B25", "C36", G44", etc from worksheet i.e "Test" and paste it into a row "A-Z" in another worksheet (i.e "AllData") where the worksheet name for "Test" worksheet matches the worksheet name listed in "AllData" column A. The data would be copied from test to AllData starting in column B. I would like it to loop through all worksheets listed an the AllData column A and stop when last one has been copied.